# O que é Partial View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, view

Usando o *Controller* eu posso retornar uma *Partial View*, JSON, *string* e outras coisas.

O que é uma Partial View? É muito usada em projetos? Porque usar ela?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

É uma parte da *view*, uma parte do código HTML que será gerado. Ele funciona como se fosse um controle que seria inserido no HTML com características próprias (hoje tem mecanismos melhor para isto, mas não quer dizer que ela não deva ser usada mais).

É comum termos páginas complexas onde ficaria difícil montar tudo como se fosse uma coisa só. Adotamos a técnica de dividir e conquistar. Cada uma destas *partial views* cuida de uma parte do conteúdo que será renderizado, formando a *view* toda.

Mas isto tem uma outra enorme vantagem, atualizações podem ser feitas de forma mais granular. Quando só uma parte da informação é atualizada, não precisa regerar toda a *view* - obviamente se a página for escrita de forma a garantir isto, provavelmente via AJAX.

Outra óbvia vantagem é que ela pode ser consumida por várias *views* diferentes.

Você pode ter *controllers/actions* ligados diretamente à estas *views* parciais ou utilizá-las em *controllers*/*actions* que gerarão outras *views*. Há sintaxe para isto. Claro que elas podem consumir seus próprios *models*.

Elas não possuem *layout*, só o conteúdo interessa.

A não ser que esteja criando páginas *old-fashioned* e muito simples, certamente ela terá muito utilidade. Então pode-se dizer que é usada em praticamente todos os projetos que se propõe usar MVC.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito obrigado,eu criei uma aqui pra testar valeu !

Comment: Um dropdown que exiba informações de uma estado que está em uma View(Model da View é a entidade Pessoa) que cadastra uma pessoa deveria ser uma Partial View?