# Como ocultar ID de URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

17/11/2016

Tenho uma aplicação que está montando a seguinte URL

**www.meusite.com.br/controller/action/id**

Porém, necessito que o `ID` não seja exibido na URL, mas deixá-lo vivo no `back-end`, porque é uma tela de pedidos, e não gostaria de deixar o `id` do pedido em exibição na URL.

Cada pedido é amarrado a uma loja, e tenho uma validação para que os somente os logins da loja `xpto` acessem os pedidos da loja `xpto`, e não pedidos de outras lojas.

Só preciso sumir com o ID da URL e deixá-lo vivo no sistema, mas ta meio complicado achar uma solução. Já li diversos artigos, mas nada esclarecedor.

Quem puder ajudar, eu agradeço muito.

18/11/2016

Marllon Nasser, segui sua ideia e fiz da seguinte maneira:

```
@this.Hidden("IdPedido").Value(item.Id)

<a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-visualizar" target="_blank" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Visualizar">
<i class="fa fa-eye">< /i>
</a>

$(function() {
  $(".btn-visualizar").click(function() {
    var pedido = $("#IdPedido").val();
    $.post("@(Url.Action(MVC.Painel.Pedidos.Visualizar()))", {
      id: pedido
    })
  });
});
```

Ele vai para o controller passando o id do pedido, só que no meu controller preciso abrir uma outra view chamada de "pedidos".

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Visualizar(int id)
{
    var user = TUser.FindByUserName(this.User.Identity.Name);
    var pedido = TOrder.Load(id);
    var xpto = pedido.Franchise.Name;
    if (user.Franchise == null || user.Franchise.Id == pedido.Franchise.Id)
    {
        //return View(pedido);
        return RedirectToAction("Visualizar", pedido);
    }
    else
    {
        TempData["Error"] = "Pedido não pertence a esta loja";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Só que não ta abrindo. Como posso fazer, por favor, alguma sugestão?

Comment: utilize `post` ao invés do `get`.

Answer (score 2):

Fiz um comentário mas resolvi colocar como resposta. Basta utilizar o protocolo `POST` ao invés do `GET`.

Falando pelo MVC em si, você não pode fazer a modificação direta no seu `ActionLink`. O `ActionLink` em si só faz a renderização do *hiperlink*.

Mas se você estiver usando MVC 3+, pode fazer uso do `Ajax.ActionLink()`, que ficaria algo como:

`@Ajax.ActionLink("Clique Aqui", "Action", "Controller", new { id = SeuId }, new AjaxOptions {HttpMethod = "POST"})`

Lembrando que para isso funcionar, você precisa incluir uma biblioteca jquery chamada `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js`. A vantagem em si dessa abordagem é que você pode informar qual o protocolo desejado.

Ou se preferir, pode fazer o uso com jQuery:

`<a id="teste_post" href="javascript:void(0);">Clique Aqui</a>`

```
$("#teste_post").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
        data: { id: SeuId },
        success: function (d) {
            //TODO
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //TODO
        }
    });
});
```

E claro, para qualquer uma das opções apresentadas, sua `action` tem de ser anotada como `[HttpPost]`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action(int id)
{
   //TODO
}
```

**EDIT**

Seguindo sua implementação, sugiro que você retorne uma [PartialView](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial) no método `Visualizar`.

Sua implementação do ajax também precisa de tratamento, ficando mais ou menos assim:

```
$(".btn-visualizar").click(function() {
  var pedido = $("#IdPedido").val();
  $.post("@(Url.Action(MVC.Painel.Pedidos.Visualizar()))", {
    id: pedido
  }).done(function(data) {
    // aqui é o retorno da controller
    var error = '@TempData["Error"]';
    if (error == null || error == "") {
      //sucesso
      $("#aDivOndeVoceVaiExibir").html(data);
    } else {
      //erro
      alert(error);
      location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "SuaController")';
    }
  });
});
```

E sua `controller` mais ou menos assim:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Visualizar(int id)
{
    var user = TUser.FindByUserName(this.User.Identity.Name);
    var pedido = TOrder.Load(id);
    var xpto = pedido.Franchise.Name;
    if (user.Franchise == null || user.Franchise.Id == pedido.Franchise.Id)
    {
        return PartialView("_Visualizar", pedido);
    }
    TempData["Error"] = "Pedido não pertence a esta loja";
    return null;
}
```

Consulte também:

- [Quais as vantagens de se utilizar os métodos HTTP corretos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49322/quais-as-vantagens-de-se-utilizar-os-m%C3%A9todos-http-corretos)
- [O que é Partial View?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/93072/o-que-%C3%A9-partial-view)

Comment: @FelipeNegro, edita sua pergunta adicionando o conteúdo que quer mostrar..

Comment: Segui sua orientação, ele vai pro controller, mas lá preciso abrir outra view. Postei o código na pergunta inicial. Se possuir alguma sugestão, por favor. E obrigadão pela ajuda!

Comment: tem como você postar o seu método `Visualizar`? Acrescenta na pergunta

Comment: Acabei de incluir

Comment: Editei a resposta com algumas sugestões, @FelipeNegro

Answer (score 1):

A melhor forma de realizar o procedimento seria por POST. Você pode deixar o id dentro do formulário em um input to tipo hidden.

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que você está fazendo essa requisição utilizando um método "get" ao invés de "post"

[Aqui](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee784233(v=cs.20).aspx) uma boa explicação!

Comment: Esse link pode ser uma boa sugestão, mas sua resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Além disso, é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui no site mesmo. Seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta. Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42/74)